# Using amsmath, ntheorem and autonum together cause an overfull hbox

Tags: amsmath, ntheorem, autonum

I'm trying to use the combination of `amsmath` + `ntheorem` + `autonum` with the `thmmarks` option enabled. This causes a bug. The minimal case to reproduce is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Compiling gives the following error message:

```
Overfull \hbox (2.22221pt too wide) detected at line 7
```

Now, I'm not a latex expert but I've been looking at the sources of these packages, and I found that the problem occurs on line `462` in `ntheorem.sty`, with the following command:

```
\make@display@tag
```

Removing this line causes the error to go away. This macro is defined in `amsmath.sty`:

```
\def\make@display@tag{%
  \if@eqnsw \incr@eqnum \print@eqnum
  \else \iftag@ \df@tag \global\let\df@tag\@empty \fi
  \fi
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \ifx\df@label\@empty
    \else
      \@xp\ltx@label\@xp{\df@label}%
      \global\let\df@label\@empty
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

I do not have enough latex expertise to know how to fix this bug, and where to report it. Anyone has suggestions?

Comment: Removing `\make@display@tag` will show no equation number in any case, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Until a better answer arrives, I fixed the error with the following redefinition of `\make@display@tag`:

```
\let\ams@make@display@tag=\make@display@tag
\renewcommand{\make@display@tag}{%
    \ifdefempty{\df@label}{% can happen with package `autonum`.
        %\ams@make@display@tag% don't execute
    }{% not empty, show refs
        \ams@make@display@tag%
    }%
}
```

I pieced this together from the internet and have no idea if it's correct. However, it does seem to work. The following also seems to work:

```
\renewcommand{\make@display@tag}{%
}
```

However, because the first option is potentially safer, I sticked with that one.

If there are better solutions I would love to hear them.